# Is it possible to create a custom file property and assign the value dynamically for a Delphi WIN32 application

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to create a custom file property for my exe, and assign a value to it in design time?

For example, see image below. I'd like to add a new file property called 'Built By', and the property value would be whoever built the current application.

[image]

Pseudo code like this:

```
Application.FileProperty.Key.Add('Built By');
Application.FileProperty.Key('Built By').Value := GetCurrentComputerName;
```

Apparently the code will have to be executed when a build is carried out. Not sure, but is this possible?

Comment: In **Project Options / Application / Version Info** you can add custom name--value pairs. They used to be displayed in the Explorer property sheet, but this feature was removed in Windows Vista or Windows 7. The data is still present, but it isn't displayed in the property sheet.

Comment: There are 3rd party apps that can display the full details, though.  Or, you can just write your own app that displays the "Built By" value using `GetFileVersionInfo()`+`VerQueryValue()`.  As for the value itself, TURN OFF the version info in the Project Options and define a custom [`VERSIONINFO`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource) resource in a separate `.RC` file that your build script can update before compiling the project. Yes, you can add custom `name=value` entries in the Project Options, but you can't set their values *dynamically* that way.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasRejbrand @RemyLebeau! Yes that makes sense. Unfortunately if we can't get the custom details to be displayed on the file properties page, it won't help too much (as it is one of the client's requirement). I'd probably just tell them that this is technically not possible.

Comment: It is possible to include more information in Details tab. Not sure how but if I right-click on Google Chrome executable I have two more entries shown in Details tab that are not shown on any executable built by Delphi. One contains trademark information about Google Chrome and another display original file name. So I'm guessing there must be limitation to just specific key names. BTW I'm on Windows 7

Comment: @SilverWarior: All my Delphi apps show my "trademark" information and the original file name, exactly as I enter them in the Project Options. But these are standard fields; previously, custom fields were also displayed (I always use a field named "Website").

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I don't knew these were also standard fields. They aren't available in Delphi by default. Where I could find a list of all standard fields?

Comment: @SilverWarior: Are you sure? They have been part of this dialog box for as far as I can remember: https://privat.rejbrand.se/dverinfo.png